# Discord.js - How to spam messages in a text channel?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot and my client wants me to have a command that spams something into a text channel.

I have tried using a for loop on its own and a while loop with a for loop as seen below:

With for and while loop:

```
    case "command":
    for(var i = 0; i >=20; i++){
        while(i <20){
            message.channel.send("spam");
        }
    }
    break;
```

With for loop:

```
case "command":
for(var i = 0; i >=20; i++){
        message.channel.send("spam");
}
break;
```

When I place a message.channel.send outside of the loop, then it shows up once.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither loop will execute because `i` starts at `0` and your loop condition states `i >= 20; i++`...

Fix your logic so that it makes sense:

```
case "command":
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        message.channel.send("spam");
    }
    break;
```